# How do scientists create an environment that favors the selection of a microbe with higher production of a certain enzyme?

Tags: microbiology, biotechnology

Let's say you want to create a strain of bacteria that is resistant to heat. You expose all bacteria to high heat and those who have mutated to survive this heat will be the survivors. Then you allow this group to reproduce and continue to gradually raise the heat until you are left with a population of highly heat-resistant bacteria.

Let's say you wanted to do the same but instead of selecting heat resistance you want to select for the production of a certain enzyme, for example amylase. How do you manipulate the environment so that only those with higher production would survive?

One thing that comes to my mind would be introducing all the microbes to an environment where the substrate they need to break down to survive is scarce. So the specimens that would create the most enzymes to break it down would survive. But then all of the other specimens would benefit too because the enzyme from the high-producing specimen would also give them the substrate they need to survive - so it would not be isolated but rather would 'carry the entire population on its back' (I have no idea whether this is how it would work, this is an idea)

Comment: Interesting, has there been a case where the enzymes did change shape to adapt? Also, wouldn't the poor enzyme producers also use up the product of the enzymatic reaction and therefore the high-producers won't be isolated?

Comment: No. Most substrates for growth have to be taken up by the cell before being metabolized. The lac operon mentioned by @user338907 contains a permease gene for this purpose.

Comment: @user338997 ? Lac permease doesn’t transport lactose into the cell?

Comment: @David Are you saying enzymes are working within the the cells? I'm pretty sure some enzymes are excreted to the environment where they break down their substrate. To clarify what i meant in the above comment i'll give an example: let's say 1 High-Amylase  producing microbe is put in an environment of scarce starch - and survives thanks to its ability to make the most out of the scarce nutrients around it - the problem is the glucose it will produce will also be available to the Low-Amylase producing microbes - who didn't contribute to survival whatsoever but still get to live on

Comment: I suggest you do a little reading on this yourself. Some substrates like proteins or polysaccharides are too large to be taken up by cells so they do excrete extracellular proteases and glycosidases to break them down into smaller molecules that can be taken up and metabolized internally. Ok, starch will not be permeable, but I was considering the general situation. If you need a group of enzymes to metabolize starch, other bacteria can only hitch a ride on the extracellular ones, which is no use if they lack the intracellular ones.

Comment: But if we take glucose for example, isn't glucose the final form of sugar needed for cellular respiration? And if there is a secretion of enzymes to the extracellular environment, and the activity of these enzymes results in free glucose in the extracellular fluid environment, then it seems these bacteria could soak it up and hitch a ride., preventing natural selection (they weren't the fittest but they were always around the fittest)

Comment: @Anonymir, It's really going to depend on your organism, the phenotypes you're selecting for, and on the goals of your experiment. I don't think there's one methodology that will work in all circumstances. As for the amylase example, I would first ask why you want to select for this? Are you planning to harvest an enzyme for specific applications downstream? Is maximizing yield important? Or are you doing simply interested in experimental evolution via positive selection?

Comment: I am interested. In the fermentation industry they use mold to make many foods taste sweet (thanks to amylase) and savory (thanks to protease) and in japan where mold-fermentation is common, they specially select spores for genetic qualities such as amylase production - in order to create the best taste of the final product. This interests me and i wonder if the process can be automated or made more efficient.